# How do you wrap the title text of a sheet in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

Wrapping the text of a cell can be done by control clicking and selecting the Wrap Text menu item so that it is checked (or by using the formatting side-bar.  However, there is no obviousuly intuitive method of wrapping the text in the zero or title cell of a sheet.

If I have a really long title text, how do I shorten the line length but keep all the title text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By going into cursor edit mode (eg, clicking into the title cell's text editing area), and then by typing the combination of 'Shift-Enter', you can insert a line break to shorten the line lengths of the title cell.